# How to fix noise from speaker when using wall power supply (but works with a battery)

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, audio, noise

I'm trying to build a simple audio amplifier for an 8 Ω speaker. The schematic/design is from [here](https://theorycircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Simple-single-transistor-audio-amplifier-circuit.png) ([Wayback Machine link just in case that link breaks](https://web.archive.org/web/20221119062109/https://theorycircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Simple-single-transistor-audio-amplifier-circuit.png)). I used a different transistor as I happened to not have the specified one, but other than that, the circuit is un-modified.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEGSmG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A battery worked, but I wanted to use a wall power supply. I found a barrel-jack wall-wart power supply that said 9V @ 1A on the back. To be safe, I plugged it into the wall, and confirmed that there was indeed 9 V coming from the barrel jack. I disconnected the battery, and connected the 9 V power supply in its place using a barrel-jack to screw-terminals (in my case, 9 V and ground). I turned it on, and strange noises came out of the speaker, seemingly at random. I'd guess maybe every few seconds, and if I try to play audio, it sounds distorted (it sounds fine with the 9 V battery).

I also tried a 5 V power supply, but I still get strange sounds (noise?) from the speaker, albeit less loudly. Found an adjustable 2 A power bench power supply (labeled "Regulated DC Power Supply"), set it to 9 V, but it also made the speaker make strange noises.

If it helps, it isn't a constant hum/buzzing. It is much more random-sounding.

I've also heard of something called a "linear" power supply, but they're pricy and big, so I'm hesitant to get one. I could also get a 9 V voltage regulator and give the regulator 12 V noisy power, but I'm not sure where to approach this from.

Unfortunately, I do not have an oscilloscope to more precisely measure the power supplies.

What's a good way to get rid of this noise so I can use a wall power supply and not a battery? Ideally I'd like to be able to keep using a normal barrel-jack power supply, if possible. I'm open to adding capacitors, a voltage regulator, etc., but I'm not sure where to begin or what to change in the circuit.

Comment: Try also using a pot for reducing input signal ...

Comment: I can add a 9v regulator. For the cap, do I just do regulator out to ground…? What size capacitor should I get? I haven’t had to deal with filtering before. I can try adding a pot to the input tomorrow as well

Comment: See figure 5 in datasheet https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf . Be aware that you need more DC input voltage. For L7809, you need ~ DC 12 V minimum already well-filtered (filtering capacitor ~ 1000 uF). If you don't have enough DC voltage, use a L7805.

Comment: It will be more work to add things to current design to remove noise.  It will be less work to start from a better design, there are even amplifier ICs which just need a few external parts to drive a speaker.

Comment: That makes sense. If I got an amplifier IC (i.e., LM386) and used it with a filtering capacitor (and maybe a regulator), would it deal with the noise itself, or would it still have issues?

Comment: Please describe the noise. 50/60 Hz humming or 6-8 kHz regulation loop chirping?

Comment: @cocomac If you have a look through the [LM386 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) you'll see it has 50 dB of "power supply rejection ratio", so it will be an improvement over a single-transistor amplifier.

Comment: @winny It's more like random static - here's a recording of it with the Regulated DC Power Supply set to 9v - https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/45187468/202864150-acffd54b-2cf5-42f6-9311-9fd678d0e544.mp4 - Andrew Morton, I'll grab an LM386 and try it

Comment: That sounds very analog and not your usual ground loop or power supply (lack of) rejection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can get with a battery or power supply not well-filtered.

[image]

[image]

If the signal is too big, BJT could be off, generating "distortion".

[image]

> How to fix noise from speaker when using wall power supply (but works with a battery

> I'm open to adding capacitors, a voltage regulator, etc.,

Although simple, you need a "good" power supply, because of the way it polarizes the BJT.
More filtering (adding a capacitor) and a regulator are needed.